# How to use web fonts in designMode?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, execcommand

I have a text editor that uses `designMode` and an `<iframe>`. I'm trying to change the font to a Google Web font. Here's the JavaScript code:

```
function rich(a,b,c) {
    editor.execCommand("styleWithCSS",true,null);
    editor.execCommand(a,b,c);
    editor.focus();
}
```

HTML for the fonts:

```
<select onchange="if (this.selectedIndex > 0) {rich('FontName',false,this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);}">
            <option selected>Font</option>
            <option>Arial</option>
            <option>Times New Roman</option>
            <option>Courier</option>
            <option>Consolas</option>
            <option>Calibri</option>
            <option>Molle</option>
        </select>
```

In the `<iframe>` file, I have this:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Molle:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I tried to use CSS to change the text into the proper font:

```
span[style="font-family: Molle"] {
    font-family: 'Molle', cursive;     
}
```

It doesn't work. A solution only has to work in Google Chrome.

Comment: What does the HTML for the span look like? Do you only have the single style in the start tag? And a space after the colon?

Comment: Yes. `<span style="font-family: Molle"></span>`

Comment: OK. But you do realise that if `font-family: Molle` worked, `font-family: 'Molle', cursive` wouldn't change anything, right? Maybe you should have written `font-style: italic` in the stylesheet.

Comment: @Mr Lister I don't think that's it, sans serif fonts work. I'll try that, though.

Comment: @MrLister Never mind about that, `font-style: italic` worked. Thanks, could you phrase it in an answer just in case someone has the same question?

Comment: OK, I did that. But italic has nothing to do with the kind of font; you can display any kind (serif, sans-serif, etc) in italic. Cursive too; cursive is simply the browser's preferred handwriting font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're loading the font, only the italic version is loaded. Therefore the font will only show if you specify italic explicitly in the span's style.

```html
font-family:'Molle',sans-serif; font-style:italic;
```

By the way, can you change the HTML at all? If so, please don't use an inline style and then try to override it with a stylesheet, using the style attribute for a selector. Not only does it look ugly and patchy, but it won't work, it won't do anything. The inline style attribute has a higher specificity than a stylesheet.
Either put in the above as the inline style for the span, or give the span a class and use that in the stylesheet to address it.

Comment: No, I can't change the HTML. The `<span>` tags are dynamically created when the user changes the font.